# Perfect matching in k-cubes

Tags: graph-theory

I want to show that every k-cube has a perfect matching for $ k \geqslant 1 $. (A k-cube is a graph whose vertices are labeled by k-tuples consisting of $ 0 $ and $1$ , and each two adjacent vertices are different in only one digit.)

According to Tutte's theorem, our graph has a perfect matching $\iff$  $$o(G-S) \leqslant \vert S \vert  $$ for all  $$S\subset V$$ where $o$ denotes the number of components with odd number of vertices, but the problem is that for arbitrary k the only way is to check all possible subsets $ S $ which is impractical and irrational. I don't think Tutte's theorem is efficient here.

Comment: (1) Why $k\ge2$, the $1$-cube also has a perfect matching. (2) The $k$-cube is a regular *bipartite* graph, so you could use the bipartite matching algorithm which is simpler than Tutte's theorem. (3) You can prove by induction on $k$ that the $k$-cube has a perfect matching. (4) You can prove by induction that (for $k\ge2$) the $k$-cube is Hamiltonian; of course a Hamiltonian graph with an even number of vertices has a perfect matching. (5) See the answer by Leen Droogendijk.

Comment: Yep, $k \geqslant 1 $. Edited.Please, no induction.I've never been good at going any further than building the induction hypothesis !

Comment: _"Please, no induction. I've never been good at"_ Isn't that the best reason for practicing induction?

Comment: @bof Hey hold on a sec there, are you sure that the "k-cube" is equivalent to "regular bipartite graph" ? 'cuase if that's the case, the marriage theorem is all we need !!!!!

Comment: No I'm not sure that "k-cube" is equivalent to "regular bipartite graph". I'm only sure of the implication in one direction; I have some doubts about the converse.

Comment: @bof Still, if a proposition is true for a regular bipartite graph, then it's true for a k-cube, 'cuase every k-cube is a regular bipartite graph. That should do the trick. Marriage theorem.

Comment: Yeah but how do you prove that a $k$-cube is bipartite? Without using induction I mean.

Comment: Good question !

Comment: In one partite set you put the numbers whose digits have an even sum, in the other you put the numbers whose digits have an odd sum. No induction required.

Comment: @Leen That shows that the k-cube is bipartite. But how can we show it's also k-regular ?

Comment: This is answered below by mlo105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Matching $\mathcal{M}(V^{\prime}, E^{\prime})$ is a subgraph of $G$ such that for any two $e_{1}, e_{2} \in E^{\prime}$, $e_{1} \cap e_{2} = \emptyset$. That is, no two edges in the matching share a common vertex. A Perfect Matching uses all the vertices of $G$.

Remember that hypercubes are constructed as follows. Given $Q_{n}$, we create a second copy of $Q_{n}$. To the first copy, we append a $0$ to the strings for each vertex. To the second copy, we append a $1$ instead.

Consider $Q_{1}$, a single edge. This is trivially a perfect matching. Now consider $Q_{2}$, which is constructed from two instances of $Q_{1}$:

```
00 - 01
|    |
10 - 11
```

Think of the left edge as the first $Q_{1}$ and the right edge as the second $Q_{1}$. If we remove the top and bottom edges of $Q_{2}$, we are left with two disjoint copies of $Q_{1}$ and a perfect matching.

Now apply this reasoning inductively. Though I think Leen Droogendijk's construction is a much cleaner way than induction. He and I are really saying the same thing, and you can apply either proof technique.

> > @Leen That shows that the k-cube is bipartite. But how can we show it's also k-regular ?

Each vertex is a binary string, and is adjacent to vertices where the two strings differ in exactly one place. We can vary exactly one character in $n$ ways. So each vertex in $Q_{n}$ has degree $n$.

Answer (score 4):

Use the representation of the $k$-cube as a binary vector of length $k$.
For each set of binary digits $b2,\ldots,b_k$ you have an edge between
$(0,b_2,\ldots,b_k)$ and $(1,b_2,\ldots,b_k)$.

Now show that this constitutes a perfect matching.

Comment: A clearer hint please ?

Comment: @elkoldo That wasn't a hint, he explicitly defined a matching. Um, what's your definition of the $k$-cube?

Comment: Well I'm not clear on how to construct that perfect matching. I wrote the definition in the problem statement.

Comment: I already have constructed the perfect matching for you. My 'binary vector of length $k$' is the same as your '$k$-tuple consisting of 0 and 1'. The two vertices I use for each edge of the matching only differ in one position. Can you be clearer about what you don't understand?

Comment: Of course; Why is it a perfect matching?

Comment: Because every vertex is matched.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how we tackle the problem: First, we put every vertex with an even degree sum in bipart $X$, and every vertex with an odd degree sum in bipart $Y$, which gives rise to a bipartition, as Leen proposed.

Then, given nod $V_{x} = (0,b_{2},b_{3},\cdots ,b_{k})$ form bipart $X$ and $V_{y} = (1,b_{2},b_{3},\cdots ,b_{k})$ from bipart $Y$ (where all $b_{j}$'s are binary), we see that each pair of such vectors disagree on one single position in exactly $k$ ways; in other words each vertex $V_{x}$ from $X$ is adjacent to exactly $k$ vertices  $V_{y}$ from $Y$ and vice versa, so that each vertex in the graph is of degree $k$, hence the graph is $k-regular$, as ml105 proposed.

Now what we have is a $bipartite$ $k-regular$ graph, for which the Marriage theorem guarantees the existence of a perfect matching.

Answer (score 0):

For k cube graph, we have 2^k number of the vertex that is even number of vertex. now arrange all the vertex in a circle and number them according to grey code. so we will have a cycle of an even number of vertices with some interconnections in-between. and we know that we have perfect matching for a cycle with an even number of vertices, hence proved.